# What does shim in fabric chaincode stand for?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I see lots of word "shim" in Hyperledger fabric chaincode samples like

```
func (t *SimpleChaincode) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, function string, args []string) ([]byte, error) {
```

which is imported from

```
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
)
```

What is shim the abbreviation of?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Shim in computing is used when referring to adapting software layers between different interfaces/components. In the context of Hyperledger Fabric, Shim [provides APIs for the chaincode to access its state variables, transaction context and call other chaincodes](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim). Shim contains the generic means for chaincode and validating peer to communicate with each other.

For more information, you can check [Chaincode Protocol specification](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/protocol-spec.md#332-chaincode-protocol)

Comment: The link for Chaincode Protocol Specification doesn't work, the following might be its alternative:
https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/blob/master/docs/protocol-spec.md